# SQL SubQuery within a Query? Possible?

Tags: sql-server

I am have 2 columns of concern:

```
 Column 1 - OFFENSE
 Column 2 - CALL_SLIP
```

I want to query every record that has "burglary”, “robbery", and "blank/null" from the offense column in January 2019 (regardless of the data in the Call_Slip column). For all blank/null records in the offense column, I then want to pull the corresponding records from the Call_Slip column that has "burg bus" or "rob individ".

This is my query:

```
 From [crimes]
 Where date_rept between '1/1/2019' and '1/31/2019'
 And offense in ('', 'robbery','burglary')
 And Call_Slip in ('burg bus', 'rob individ')
```

This is what I get:

```
 OFFENSE    CALL_SLIP
```

```
 Robbery        Rob Individ
 Robbery        Kidnapping
                Burg Bus
                Accident
                Alarm
 Burglary       Burg Bus
                DWI
                Rob Individ
                Warrant
 Robbery        Carjacking
```

This is what I want to get:

```
 OFFENSE    CALL_SLIP
```

```
 Robbery    Rob Individ
 Robbery    Kidnapping
            Burg Bus
 Burglary   Burg Bus
            Rob Individ
 Robbery    Carjacking
```

How can I query what I want from the `offense` column and then from those results query what I want from the `Call_Slip` column? Using the query I created above, it queries both columns simultaneously which doesn't return `Call_Slips` names outside of burg bus or rob individ. The offense could be a robbery, but the Call_Slip name may be kidnapping, which is okay. Now if the offense is null and the Call_Slip is kidnapping, then it is not okay. 
I truly hope this makes sense to someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT *
From [crimes]
Where date_rept between '1/1/2019' and '1/31/2019'
And ((offense = '' And Call_Slip in ('burg bus', 'rob individ'))
OR  (offense is null And Call_Slip in ('burg bus', 'rob individ'))
OR  (offense in ('robbery','burglary')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the conditions using an OR statement for example

```
--SELECT columns
  From [crimes]
 Where date_rept between '1/1/2019' and '1/31/2019'
   And ( (
           offense in ('robbery','burglary')
          )
        OR (
             offense in ('') AND Call_Slip in ('burg bus', 'rob individ')
           )
        )
```

Comment: Thank you George, I did try the OR statement and the issue is that it disregards the Offense conditions.

Comment: Just looked at your question one more time and i am thinking how is it possible that you have call_slip values like Accident, Alarm when your where condition filters them out(And Call_Slip in ('burg bus', 'rob individ'))

Comment: Because it would satisfy the condition of Offense being blank.

Comment: You had an AND clause along with the offense in('','robbery','burglary)' which meant, even if  there was a row with  column offense as '' the row would be returned only if the corresponding Call_Slip value must be either 'burg_bus' or 'rob_individ'?

Comment: Here is a dbfiddle link which explains what i am trying to say https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c16a40157a7c89a22e6bf57158b3f0db

Comment: Thank you George! Totally makes sense!